# Manually initializing a dynamic DOM element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How does one initialize a dom element that is manually inserted to the dom in angular?

angular.bootstrap doesn't seem to work in this case, since I already initialize the app with ng-app. I just want to initialize the new dom element, not the whole app.
`angular.bootstrap($('#my-new-element'), ['MyApp'])` works but is problematic since it creates a new instance of the app on the new dom element instead of adding the new element and controller into the existing app.

I am thinking there must be a way of getting the $compile from the injector and compiling the new element with the html to get the linking function, but not sure what to pass for the scope there.

Comment: How are you do insertion of the new element? If you do it in directive then you can pass the scope of the directive. If you do it somwhere else, you need to do it in a directive, because it's only correct angularjs way.

Comment: I am doing the insertion outside angular unfortunately, since this is a legacy app.